# java sound amplifier method

Tags: java, audio, arraylist

I have an assignment for a class that has to do with implementing arraylists to work with sounds in java. I have tried to write the method but keep getting this error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:-254 (in java.util.ArrayList)

I am new to programming so I may have missed something quite simple. Anyway, here is my current method:

```
public void amplify (double amt) {
    for(Integer i : myData){
        myData.set(i, (int)(myData.get(i) * amt));
    }
}
```

Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is myData? what is its type?

Comment: myData is the ArrayList of Integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this you just create a local variable `j` and when you want to set the `ArrayList` use it like a `index` like below:

```
        public void amplify (double amt) {
         int j =0;
        for(Integer i : myData){
            myData.set(j, (int)(myData.get(i) * amt));
            j++;
        }
      }
```

Comment: I still get the same error. However, the method works if I use a normal for loop instead of an enhanced one.

Comment: @Alec Bohnett I tested it and it works but i can't see the problem

Comment: I have found my problem guys, since it was an enhanced for loop, i is the actual value instead of the index, so it should have been just i instead of myData.get(i). That is way out of the list's boundaries. Thank you all for responding so fast!!